# One or more parameter values were invalid: Type mismatch for key xyz expected: S actual: M

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, type-mismatch

My AWS Lambda calls a DynamoDB based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33649402/495455

I get an error:

**One or more parameter values were invalid: Type mismatch for key UserName expected: S actual: M**

This is python code yet the error occurs with JavaScript & etc as well:

```
import json
import boto3
client = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = client.Table("DS-Users")

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    UserName = event['UserName']
    Email = event['Email']
    Score = event['Score']
    Mobile = event['Mobile']
    CountryId = event['CountryId']
    Level = event['Level']
    Magic = event['Magic']

    table.put_item(Item={'UserName':{'S':UserName},'Email':{'S':Email},'Score':{'N':Score},'Level':{'N':Level},'Mobile':{'S':Mobile},'Magic':{'S':Magic}})

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(event)
    }
```

Researching the error results in a few answers that don't resolve the above error:

1. https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-document-js-sdk/issues/17
2. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=248424

I'm stumped because UserName is a string, I enforce it in the Integration Request Mapping Template:

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{
  "UserName" : "$inputRoot.UserName",
```

Any idea's? Why is it treating the string as a model data type?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

First note the version of the AWS SDK V1 vs V2!

Also note the syntax for the client vs resource API of boto3. `{'UserName':{'S':UserName}` is the syntax used for the boto3 client and this solution is for the boto3 resource variant.

boto3 client put_item reference  –
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.put_item

boto3 resource put_item reference - https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Table.put_item

**client syntax**

`{'UserName':{'S':UserName},`

**resource syntax**

`{'UserName':UserName,`

For my specific case, this fixed it up:

```
table.put_item(Item={'UserName':UserName,'Email':Email,'Score':Score,'Level':Level,'Mobile':Mobile,'Magic':Magic})
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your fix, it helped me too. :)

Comment: Cheers, wasted far too much time following the old docs by mistake :)

Comment: for additional context, OP seems to be confused with the syntax for the client vs resource API of boto3. 

`{'UserName':{'S':UserName}` is the syntax used for the boto3 client and this solution is for the boto3 resource variant.

[boto3 client put_item reference](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.put_item)

[boto3 resource put_item reference](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Table.put_item)

Comment: This will also happen if you are looking at the AWS Javascript docs vs the NodeJS docs :(

Comment: There is also some funny behavior if you access your dynamo client from a dynamo resource, i.e. `boto3.resource('dynamodb').meta.client.` See https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/2125

Answer (score 0):

### Check your Primary Key Type on DynamoDB Table

When you create a AWS DynamoDB table, you are required to set a **Primary Key name & type** (see details here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.CoreComponents.html#HowItWorks.CoreComponents.PrimaryKey)

> Each primary key attribute must be a scalar (meaning that it can hold only a single value). The only data types allowed for primary key attributes are **string, number, or binary**. There are no such restrictions for other, non-key attributes.

#### Send key value without dictionary info on type

Using boto3, when you go to `put_item(Item='...)`, you do *not* need to include the type information for the Primary key. Dynamo expects the type you set on table creation, so of course it's not necessary to pass that info again.

The error **Type mismatch for key UserName expected: S actual: M** is accurate in that you are passing a dictionary (i.e. Map or "M" type):

- `'UserName':{'S':UserName},...`

Instead of passing a string (i.e. your event['UserName'])

- `'UserName': UserName,...`