# how to put websocket connection ID to dynamodb use lambda python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

currently, I'm making a serverless chat server using aws Websocket gateway
how to put websocket connection ID to dynamodb use lambda python?

I can't do anything because I don't understand.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you set up apiGateway to connect to lambda already on connection? If so this answer might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/33649402/8562442